Arrays in cpp: Write a program to reverse the elements of an array of size 7
I wrote the following code to reverse the elements of an array of size 7 in C++. The goal is to print the elements of the array in reverse order. Here's the code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int arr[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

For example, if the input array is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, the output should be {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}.
Before I proceed, I want to confirm:
Is this code correct for the purpose of reversing the array and printing it?
Are there any improvements or best practices I should follow in similar scenarios?
Thanks in advance for your help!

You print the array in reverse, but the array and its elements will stay unmodified. You're not reversing the array. What is your actual assignment? What is its actual and exact wording? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Your code doesn't reverse anything so no this is not the correct way to reverse an array.

I would say the elements are printed in reverse order, not that they are reversed within the container, which is what I expect the assignment requires.

details matter. is it your task to reverse an array and then print it? Or is your task to print the elements of an array in reversed order? You say both but thats very different tasks actually

Looks like someone is teaching you "C" not C++, in C++ use std::array<int,7> values{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};  for (auto value : values | std::views::reverse) { std::cout << value << " "; } or use std::reverse to write code that shows WHAT it does


"Is this code correct for the purpose of reversing the array and printing it?"

Your program does not actually reverse the array elements. It iterates backwards and prints elements in reverse order, but the array itself remains unchanged.
In order to reverse the array, you can iterate from the beginning until half the array size and swap each element with its counterpart from the end.
Such a function may be written as follows:
template <std::size_t N>
void reverse(int (& arr)[N])
{
    using std::swap;

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N/2; ++i)
        swap(arr[i], arr[N-1-i]);
}

Example

Of course, as mentioned in @Jarod42's comment, you can simply use std::reverse from the standard library that is available for that purpose.
Aside from exercise purposes, this is what you are supposed to use.

or even use std::reverse.

Or std::views::reverse

@PepijnKramer: std::views::reverse just gives a reverse view of the data, about like the question (except it uses iterators, so pretty much a loop from rbegin() to rend() (or crbegin()/crend()).

@JerryCoffin Yes that's true. I should have added that OP can use this if all he needs is to print backward

if OP cannot use std, std::swap would also be problematic ;-)

@Jarod42 Not it's not about std but about working on the algorithm. I think OP's teacher wants them to find the solution by themselves before using std::reverse. But anyway, giving the solution as I did also remove the purpose of the exercise (hence why I removed my comment :D)

I edited the answer to add a mention to std::reverse since you're right that's the right thing to use (apart from exercise purposes)
